# The memory usage shown in memory profiler is different from Process Explorer

Tags: wpf, memory, memory-leaks

I'm learning to use [.Net Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/) and testing the memory usage of [Microsoft's DataBindingLab sample project](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=wpfsamples&DownloadId=7747).

.Net Memory Profiler shows total live bytes are 2011015, ie. 2MB.
[image: .Net Memory Profiler]

Process Explorer shows Private Bytes are 56MB.
[image: Process Explorer]

Obviously, there is such a big difference between the value given by the two tools. Where does the remaining 54MB come from?